# What is Tycho in Eclipse and do I have to learn to love it?

Tags: maven, pdfbox, tycho

I have been trying to install an Apache project (PDFBox) using

```
mvn install
```

and this then caused some plugins (Tycho) to be installed in my Eclipse apparently automatically, after which my Eclipse stopped working and I had to  delete everything and re-install Eclipse.

I have done a moderate amount of Maven work but have never seen Tycho and have not yet learnt to love it. I can't see how to install PDFBox without Tycho but I don't trust things I don't understand. Is it essential? and if so how do I get it to install without breaking all my other Eclipse projects?

Comment: mvn install build and installs the artifact in your local repository. If you would like to use pdfbox you simply gave that as dependency. I think you should about using Maven more in detail.

Comment: @khmarbaise do I have to use Tycho if I am using Eclipse on the PDFBox distrib?

Comment: You would need to ask on the PDFBox mailing lists these questions. If this is an Eclipse Plugin or RCP application then **yes** you will need to use tycho to build it.  I assume there should be build instructions.  At a minimum you need Maven 3 installed and "mvn install" should do the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @Bae is the closest to an answer